# stuck on using addEventListener

Tags: javascript

im at javascript and dom. what i'd like to do with the below codes is when i append a tr and click the 2nd td (last name), the 2nd td value will be changed bold. then when i click the 2nd td value again, it will get back to normal. i've done with changing it bold but i cant make it go back to normal. i know if i add a button with onclick method calling detHandler. but i am not allowed to make a button for that. i need to click that name again to go back to normal. do you guys have any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function appendUser()
  {
    var fname=prompt("Please enter your First Name");
    var lname=prompt("Please enter your Last Name");
    var email=prompt("Please enter your Email Address");

    var table=document.getElementById("appendable");

    var tr=document.createElement("tr");
    var td1=document.createElement("td");
    var td2=document.createElement("td");
    td2.id="p1";
    var td3=document.createElement("td");

    td1.innerHTML = fname;
    td2.innerHTML = lname;
    td3.innerHTML = email;

    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    tr.style.color="green";

    table.appendChild(tr);

    addHandler();


  }

  function addHandler ()
  {
    var addH = document.getElementById('p1');

    if (addH.addEventListener) 
    {
      addH.addEventListener('click', applyStyle, false);
    }
    else if (addH.attachEvent) 
    {
      addH.attachEvent('onclick', applyStyle);
    }
  }

  function detHandler ()
  {
    alert("aa");
    var detH = document.getElementById('p1');

    if (detH.removeEventListener)
    {
      detH.removeEventListener('click', applyStyle, false);
      detH.style.color="blue";
      //detH.style.fontWeight="normal";
    }
    else if (detH.detachEvent)
    {
      detH.detachEvent('onclick', applyStyle);
    }
  }

  function applyStyle ()
  {
    var add = document.getElementById('p1');
    add.style.fontWeight="bold";
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="appendable" width='50%' border='1'><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>          
 <th>Email Address</th></tr>
     </tr></table>
    <p><button onclick="appendUser()">Append New Row</button></p>
</body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just toggle it in the handler

```
function applyStyle (){
    var add  = document.getElementById('p1');
    var curr = add.style.fontWeight;

    add.style.fontWeight = curr != 'bold' ? 'bold' : 'inherit';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gzc4Z/)

Answer (score 0):

It is this line:

```
if (addH.addEventListener)
```

In the W3C model, you cannot find out whether an event is registered on an element or not.

Comment: It checks if the property exists on the element

Comment: Technically, it evaluates the property's value as either truthy or falsy. Checking to see if the property existed would be done with `in` or `hasOwnProperty` instead.

Comment: Interesting... I always did it using this: var ev = $._data(element, 'events');
if(ev && ev.click) alert('click bound');

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate IDs in your code (every row will have a cell with `id="pq"`!)

Consider this solution:

```
function appendUser()
{
  var fname=prompt("Please enter your First Name");
  var lname=prompt("Please enter your Last Name");
  var email=prompt("Please enter your Email Address");

  var table=document.getElementById("appendable");

  var tr=document.createElement("tr");
  var td1=document.createElement("td");
  var td2=document.createElement("td");
  var td3=document.createElement("td");

  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fname));
  td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lname));
  td2.setAttribute("data-toggleme","true"); // this is how we identify the cell
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(email));

  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  tr.appendChild(td3);
  tr.style.color="green";

  table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById('appendable').onclick = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
  while( t != this && t.nodeName != "TD") t = t.parentNode;
  if( t.getAttribute("data-toggleme")) {
    t.style.fontWeight = t.style.fontWeight == "bold" ? "" : "bold";
  }
}
```

Deferring event handlers like this is great for two reasons:

1. Fewer event handlers! Makes the browser faster not having to keep track of so much.
2. It is future-proof in that you can add more rows and they will "automatically" be handled correctly